# Using base table's field in sub query not working

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

For a somewhat complicated query I'm using a base query with some functional subqueries which use the base table's `order.id`

```sql
SELECT
order.id as order_id,
( sub1 ) as products,
( sub2 ) as sum_transactions
FROM `order`
WHERE `order`.`id` IN (768, 123, 5674, ...)
```

Both sub queries query other tables and use the `order.id` in it.
eg Sub1 looks like this:

```sql
-- sub1
SELECT sum(cents * nof) FROM products WHERE products.order_id = order.id
```

So far so good.

For the second sub query I'm running into a problem when referencing to the `order.id` This is the query itself:

```sql
-- sub2
SELECT sum(x.amount)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT transactions.payment_id as payment_id, 
    transactions.amount as amount
  FROM payment_status as ps
  LEFT JOIN transactions ON ps.payment_id = transactions.payment_id
  WHERE ps.status = 'paid'
  AND transactions.order_id = order.id
) as x
```

This query results in an `Unknown column 'order.id' in 'where clause'` If i replace the order.id with an actual number the query works. So i'm guessing the 'order' table is not available in the FROM? While it is available in the first subquery?

You might ask why the `distinct` and the need of the `FROM ... as x`. Let me explain it.

I want to sum the total amount of 'paid' transactions. But: 1 - there could be multiple transactions per order. And 2 - every transaction could have multiple 'paid' messages. The PSP could sent multiple paid updates, so I don't want the transaction to show up twice in the result.

So my question is two-fold:
1: How could I reference to the `order.id` within the second subquery?
2: If not possible, how could I rewrite the subquery to get the total of paid transactions?

Answer (score 0):

If by adding the column `order_id` of the table `transactions` in the `SELECT` list of the subquery you get the same results then instead of the subquery, use a `LEFT` join and aggregate:

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id,
      (SELECT SUM(p.cents * p.nof) FROM products p WHERE p.order_id = o.id) AS products,
      SUM(t.amount) AS sum_transactions
FROM `order` o
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT t.order_id, t.payment_id, t.amount
  FROM payment_status AS ps LEFT JOIN transactions t
  ON ps.payment_id = t.payment_id
  WHERE ps.status = 'paid'
) t ON t.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.id IN (768, 123, 5674, ...)
GROUP BY o.id
```